# Custom font and link box

Tags: css, font-face

I use font-face to display a link in a custom font. 
But the font has big letters, so the link box doesn't match with the rendered text.

How can I resolve that ?

Comment: can you show your code? your question seem too broad.

Comment: In fact I had a link in there before, but as I was working on the web server the display changed and I'm now using display: block on the link.

Answer (score 0):

try adding CSS:

```
display:table-cell
```

in the `<p>` before the span and the link

Comment: Doesn't work. I will probably just display the link as a block and set bigger height and width